# Connection Timeout Error for WEP security

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network

I'm connecting my MacBook Pro to a router which uses WEP security. It shows a *Connection Timeout* error every half an hour. The security level of the router can't be changed, since its a common router. Other Mac systems are having no problems with it.

So far I've tried removing the network from the **System Preferences/Network** panel and restarting the router and the computer, with no luck. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Different devices use different wireless chipsets. Although most should be compatible sometimes they don't work well together.

Did you try to update the router's firmware? A newer one might correct some glitches.

Comment: I didnt try so far..Is there any changes can be done in my macbook?..

Comment: I'm afraid no. If it always happens at about the same time it's most probably related to some wireless inconsistencies.